# Error while transferring data from Azure Data Lake to Oracle db

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to copy bulk data from Azure Data Lake to Oracle db . It has 58 columns and almost 87000 rows . but I am getting below error ,"[Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-39776:fatal Direct Path API error loading table "####" ORA-03137:malformed TTC packet from client rejected:[klaprs_11][26][512][70][60][666][][]".I even tried reducing the columns but even if column count is 26 it fails. Even if I reduce 2-3 columns, sometimes it fails .Column behaviour is quite inconsistent.

Comment: What exactly are you using to transfer data? Full Oracle version? Have you tried to disable datapump compression? klaprs_11 is a loader parser function

Comment: I am using Azure Data Factory - copy activity. Haven't tried disabling datapump compression .I am not much aware of Oracle side

Comment: I don't have access to check what those magic numbers in the error mean (email me details if you want me to follow up), but check for corrupt (unexpected) data from Azure.  Also check your code is programmed correctly.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I resolved this issue earrlier by changing varchar to nvarchar for my columns in Oracle table . It worked well , but now for another environment I am getting this error "ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-39776: fatal Direct Path API error loading table "abc" ORA-03137: malformed TTC packet from client rejected: [klaprs_90] [1] [6] [9] [45] [] [] []"